# Error while installing RVM using Curl in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, curl, rvm

I was trying to install `RVM` using `Curl` in Ubuntu 14.04.

I ran the following command:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

And got the following error:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to get.rvm.io port 80: Network is unreachable
```

Any help to resolve this issue is highly appreciable. Thanks

Comment: And you can visit this url in browser, right?

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: @zishe Yes I am able to visit the url in browser

Comment: @Vimsha Yes, the system is connected to internet

Comment: I found the answer here : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails

Comment: @user2002522 even the answer here did not work

Answer (score 9):

Try this before execute curl:

```
   echo ipv4 >> ~/.curlrc
```

Answer (score 2):

curl is used to download files via HTTP much like wget and it means that a connection to the remote site is failing which is why it is unable to download.  Saw this on another forum, 
give it a shot and see if it works for you:

"replace the `get.rvm.io` part with `raw.github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer` -it's the same script, just takes out some potential DNS problems on rvm's end"

Refere to this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails